# Objective-C How To Use observeValueForKeyPath To Check Status Of AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

My current code is:

```
...
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:video];
    _videoDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);

    AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
    _player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    [_player addObserver:self
              forKeyPath:@"status"
                 options:0
                 context:nil];
...


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == _player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (_player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"PLAYING");
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason, the observeValueForKeyPath isn't even firing. I was wondering if I did something wrong or if my code is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is theoretically possible for the player's status to change even before your KVO registration which would mean that no further KVO callbacks are made.

I would suggest that you add the following option when performing the KVO registering - `NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial`. This ensures that you will receive a callback for the initial value as well.

```
[_player addObserver:self
          forKeyPath:@"status"
             options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial)
             context:nil];
```

Comment: Um...this works most of the time, but when the video that is 10 seconds long...I check to see if the avplayer's status is ready to play, and if it is, i play the video. But thing is, when I play the video there is still a small delay (about 1 second) before it actually starts playing the video. How come this is happening, even though the status is ready to play? How can i fix this?

Comment: AVPlayer's status can be ready to play even though it hasn't loaded the actual data. Observe the status for AVPlayer.currentItem and it will give you a more accurate value. Also, even though AVPlayerItem.status will report ready, you can still see a delay because the player would buffer some video to ensure continuous playback without stalling.

Comment: How do you think I should account for this delay because I display a video duration bar that winds down based on the videos duration, so of the video is delayed, the video duration bar starts too early

Comment: I assume the video duration you are talking about is the amount of playback time remaining in the video? If so, then why is the video time winding down when the video hasn't even started? Are you using a timer to start the clock that counts down how much playback has occurred?

Comment: Oh, I was just getting the avplayer's duration, and doing a UIView animation with that duration. How would I do it with the playback time?

Comment: You could create a periodic timer and whenever it fires, update the position based on the value of `AVPlayer.currentTime`, or attach periodic time observers to the player using `-addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:` and whenever the block is called, update the value with the time passed as the block's argument.